# Not Receiving Fire base OTP message

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am new to Android development. I am not getting OTP message from Fire base but if I enter the code manually then it works. I am not sure why I am not getting text message. Your help is highly appreciated. I am not sure whether I am doing correctly sendVerificationcode method correctly or not.

Steps Completed:
 1) I added GSON file to app directory
 2) I added test phone number in the firebase console
 3) I added SHA1 code to fire base
 4) I added SMS permission in the Android manifest file.
 5) I enabled firebase authentication in Android studio
 6) I tried different phone numbers too

```
VerifyPhoneActivity.java
public class VerifyPhoneActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private String verificationId;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_verify_phone);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editTextCode);

        String phonenumber = getIntent().getStringExtra("phonenumber");
        sendVerificationCode(phonenumber);

        findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String code = editText.getText().toString().trim();

                if (code.isEmpty() || code.length() < 6) {

                    editText.setError("Enter code...");
                    editText.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
              verifyCode(code);
            }
        });

    }

   private void verifyCode(String code) {
    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);
    signInWithCredential(credential);
 }



    private void signInWithCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
  // private void signInWithCredential(PhoneAuthCredential) {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(VerifyPhoneActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

                            startActivity(intent);

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(VerifyPhoneActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void sendVerificationCode(String number) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                number,
                60,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD,
                mCallBack
        );

    }

    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
            mCallBack = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
            super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
            verificationId = s;
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
            String code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
            if (code != null) {
                editText.setText(code);
                verifyCode(code);
            }

            System.out.println("Hello Phone Number"+code);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            Toast.makeText(VerifyPhoneActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
}
```

Below code looks like not working:

```
@Override
public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
    String code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
   // String code="000000";
    if (code != null) {
        editText.setText(code);
        verifyCode(code);
    }

    System.out.println("Hello Phone Number2"+code);
}
```

Comment: Did you check the stack trace?? getting any exception or anything?

Comment: 2018-11-21 02:24:09.543 1893-1907/system_process I/GnssLocationProvider: WakeLock released by handleMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@f7129de)

Comment: Nothing useful error message.

Comment: remove `super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);` on `onCodeSent`

Comment: Disabled this line but still I didn't receive the OTP number. //super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);

Comment: @RakeshKumar I think onVerificationCompleted method is not working for me becuase I am not getting the code value. What might be the issue?

Comment: Are you using emulator cause on emulators it will not work ? And check if you are providing your country code before your number suppose in my case it's +91

Answer (score 0):

Use like this following:

`onCreate`

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks()
        {

            @Override
            public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential)
            {
                // This callback will be invoked in two situations:
                // 1 - Instant verification. In some cases the phone number can be instantly
                //     verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.
                // 2 - Auto-retrieval. On some devices Google Play services can automatically
                //     detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verificaiton without
                //     user action.
                Log.d(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted:" + credential);

                Log.e("number","credential=-=-=>>><<>>>signInWithPhoneAuthCredential-->>");
                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);

            }
            @Override
            public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e)
            {
                // This callback is invoked in an invalid request for verification is made,
                // for instance if the the phone number format is not valid.
                Log.e(TAG, "onVerificationFailed", e);

                // Show a message and update the UI
                // ...
            }



            @Override
            public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
                                   PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token)
            {

                // The SMS verification code has been sent to the provided phone number, we
                // now need to ask the user to enter the code and then construct a credential
                // by combining the code with a verification ID.
                Log.e(TAG, "onCodeSent:" + verificationId+"<<token>>"+token);

                // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
                mVerificationId = verificationId;

                //mResendToken = token;

                // ...
            }
        };

        //String phoneNumber=Settings.PREFIX + Settings.PREFIX_PHONE;

        String phoneNumber="your phone number with prefix";

        Log.e("number","credential=-=-=>>>22222>>"+phoneNumber);

        if(phoneNumber!=null && !phoneNumber.isEmpty())
        {
            startPhoneNumberVerification(phoneNumber);
        }
```

Method:

```
private void startPhoneNumberVerification(String phoneNumber)
    {
        Log.e("startPhoneNumber","startPhoneNumberVerification------>>"+phoneNumber);
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
                60,                 // Timeout duration
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
                mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
        Log.e("startPhoneNumber","startPhoneNumberVerification--2222222---->>"+phoneNumber);
    }
```

Method:

```
private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential)
    {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
                    {
                        if (task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.e(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");



                        } else
                            {
                            // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                            Log.e(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException)
                            {

                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: I compared your code and my code both looks same but still not sure why the method is invoked.

Comment: Which method not invoked in this code? Did you give that try??

Comment: @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

            Log.d(TAG,"onVerificationCompleted:" + phoneAuthCredential);

            String code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
           // String code="000000";
            if (code != null) {
                editText.setText(code);
              // verifyCode(code);
                signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);

                System.out.println("Hello Phone Number2"+code);
            }


        }

Comment: this method is having issue now.

Comment: Have you tried this code that I shared above??? was that worked for you?? Are you getting the exception of firebase or any other exception???

Comment: Your code looks pretty much same but my concern is why my code is not working?